# Stability of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Kernel Linux-5.4.0-26-generic

Tags: kernel, compatibility

I installed a barebone version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with only kernel (no DE,Window Manger and the usual things that comes with Ubuntu).i wanted to know,if possible,will this kernel work alright with 18.04 LTS.No reason to believe otherwise to be honest.Just i have arch installed on the same machine and i dont want to tinker around with it too much.Thanks.

If i may ask in this same question,just this one time since they are related , i could not find the header for this kernel with the source list that was generated during installation. What repository ami missing and how to get it? This actually got me a little worried hence the first question.Sorry if i sound silly and this is a non issue.
Thanks again.

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? Presumably you mean 18.04 and not 8.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at the following link. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2FSupport.A18.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support

Ubuntu provide a hardware enablement stack which gives you more up to date kernels on older LTS releases. It’s a simple install that should solve both questions.

Comment: Thank you.The biggest problem i have is it cannot recognize any network interface including the wired ethernet one. In chroot it was fine.I could work with Android  usb tethered.I have also build and done a dkms install of the driver for an USB wifi device that works in Arch,another Ubuntu on my laptop.Seems to be a generic problem.Need some elp pls.thanks

Comment: ip link shows lo only.no errors on lshw -C network

Comment: Have you installed NetworkManager or similar? If you are familiar with Arch you will probably installed networkmanager or dhcpcd to get networking operational as part of a minimal install

Comment: I have Network Manager,dhcpcd.The problem is the network interface itself is not recognized, As if the driver was not loaded or not present.It should list atleast for the wired Ethernet and the Android tethered USB interface.In the chroot environment it does.And so does the installer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work . If you are using 18.0.4 LTS then expect major system problems as simple things like networking,distorted display (GPU acceleration) to be very unstable as i found out. You are better of not upgrading directly to 5.4 without a clear migration path that Ubuntu recommends. This is speaking from a personal experience